# Using v-attr with attribute that contains colon 'xmlns:href' does not compile

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js

I am trying to use v-attr to add an attribute that contains a colon which is a delimiter for Vuejs key:value. It doesn't compile.

```
<svg>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        v-attr="xmlns:href: '#' + iconID"></use>
</svg>
```

I have also tried

```
<svg class="lego-icon">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xmlns:href="#[[ iconID ]]"></use>
</svg>
```

Which has similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used vue.js, but looking at [the source for v-attr](https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/blob/master/src/directives/attr.js#L1), it appears as if it is designed to handle xlink:href.

The trouble is your attribute is wrong.  It should be `xlink:href`, not `xmlns:href`.  Try:

```
<svg>
    <use v-attr="xlink:href: '#' + iconID"></use>
</svg>
```

(If you are embedding SVG in an HTML page, you shouldn't need the `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`).

Comment: I have the same problem and unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work: I always get this error: `[Vue warn]: Invalid expression. Generated function body:  scope.href:'/svg/ico.svg#'+scope.option.icon`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your xlink:href in quotes so that Vue doesn't treat the colon as an argument separator (https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/issues/648)

```
<use v-attr="'xlink:href' : '#' + iconID">
```

Comment: This is the valid answer

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of `vue.js`, you can use

```
<use v-bind:href="'#icon-' + iconId"></use>
```

or even

```
<use :href="'#icon-' + iconId"></use>
```

`Vue.js` seems to automatically set the attribute with the right namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:[attrName]="attrValue"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                attrName : 'xlink:href',
                attrValue : '...',
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```